# Can one use spellsong and versatile performance with perform act while undercover?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, skills, bard

[This](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spellsong/) is the feat in question.

> You can conceal the activity of casting a bard spell by masking it in
>   a performance. As a swift action, you may combine your casting time of
>   a spell with a Perform check. Observers must make a Perception or
>   Sense Motive check opposed by your Perform check to realize you are
>   also casting a spell.

With the way it's worded, and the way [versatile performance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/#TOC-Versatile-Performance-Ex-) is, can one feasibly use perform (act) while using spell song, to stay in character while no one is the wiser?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. Why is versatile performance relevant?

Comment: Versatile Performance let's you -effectively- use perform (act) in place of bluff and disguise. -I think- OP is asking if you can make a perform (act) check to hide a spell while also using perform (act) to bluff or disguise yourself to stay undercover.

Answer (score 0):

[Versatile Performance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/#TOC-Versatile-Performance-Ex-) lets a Bard "use his bonus in that skill in place of his bonus in associated skills". It doesn't means that it requires you to actually perform to use these skill, just that you take your bonus in perform instead of your bonus in the skill.

When using the feat the feat you have to actually perform. You have to make a Perform check but it doesn't mean that it gives you a free action: it just makes you do one check and that's it. You can roleplay how your act looks like while you cast the spell but you can't use that check for something more than what it is required for (like an other action that would also require a Perform check).

Comment: Sounds like one massive grey area

Comment: It's not. Really: you can do your roleplay of actor but Versatile Performance is not implied here.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the heart of the question here is "can I use Perform (Act) to function as a Disguise check, and while so disguised, use Perform (Act) to set the Perception or Sense Motive DC for Spellsong?"

If I have the correct understanding, the answer is, in effect, **yes**. You make a Disguise check, and make use of Versatile Performance to make the check using your Perform (Act) bonus in place of your Disguise bonus. It is worth noting that you are not technically making a Perform (Act) check when you do this; you are merely using the bonus from that skill in place of your Disguise bonus. [Disguise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/disguise) offers no indication that you are unable to execute any particular actions after having used the skill to create a disguise. Therefore, you are able to cast spells. When you do, you can utilize the Spellsong feat to conceal the casting.

While the above paragraph  points out that you technically are operating under the effects of a Disguise check while making a Perform check, there would still be nothing wrong with this if you were indeed gaining the benefits of two distinct Perform checks simultaneously. There is no rule, to my knowledge, that precludes the possibility of making a skill check while in the process of making a check with the same skill. For example, one would be able to use [Acrobatics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics) to Move Through Threatened Squares while in the process of completing the movement enabled by an Acrobatics check to Cross Narrow Surfaces/Uneven Ground.